# Aggregate functions in subselect T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm just starting out in T-SQL and trying to code up an update but I need an aggregate function in my subselect, which I can't seem to have.

This is what I currently have

```
Update Roysched
Set Royalty = (Royalty - 2)
Where title_id in (select title_id from sales where SUM(qty) > 30)
```

But I get an error regarding aggregates in subselects

What would be the workaround for this?

Comment: You need to use having sum(qty) > 30 instead of where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aggregate terms in the `where` clause - that's what the `having` clause is for. Note that you're also missing the `group by` clause:

```
UPDATE roysched
SET    royalty = (royalty - 2)
WHERE  title_id IN (SELECT   title_id
                    FROM     sales
                    GROUP BY title_id
                    HAVING   SUM(qty) > 30)
```